# Python replace double double quotes reading File

Tags: python

In a file that I would like to convert to json I have this:

```
""status"":200,""ts"":1543039907796,""userAgent"":"Mozilla 5.0""..... <- (It's variable)
```

I would like to replace `""` for `"`, I mean:

```
"status":200,"ts":1543039907796,"userAgent":"Mozilla 5.0"......
```

I'm reading a log file with a json format like this:

```
def process_log_file(cur, filepath):
    # open log file
    with open(filepath) as json_file:
        data = json_file.read().replace('\n', ',').replace('\\"', '').replace('\\/"', '').replace('\/"', ' ').replace('\/', ' ')
        df = pd.read_json(data)
```

In this line:   data = json_file.read().replace('\n', ',').replace('\"', '').replace('\/"', '').replace('/"', ' ').replace('/', ' ')

I've tried with:

```py
replace('""', '"')

replace("""""", "")

replace('(")(")','"')
```

and It does not work. somebody knows why?

Comment: What output you got after `replace('""', '"')`?

Comment: Just nothing change

Comment: I copied your input and executed `string.replace('""', '"')`, double double quotes got replace.

Comment: In my case '""status"":200,""ts"":1543039907796,""userAgent"":"Mozilla 5.0""' it was just an example. I mean is a huge file with json format so is variable... the """ appears just in some places, that file comes from a process and actually is a log file

Comment: Your actual attempt doesn't contain `.replace('""', '"')` - did you just forget to put it in the code?

Comment: In this line: data = json_file.read().replace('\n', ',').replace('\"', '').replace('\/"', '').replace('/"', ' ').replace('/', ' ')

I've tried with:

replace('""', '"')

replace("""""", "")

replace('(")(")','"')

Answer (score 4):

You can be more intelligent than exact string matches in regex, your regex can look like:

```
re.sub('"+', '"', '""status"":200,""ts"":1543039907796,""userAgent"":"Mozilla 5.0""')
```

It will replace all double quotes where there are multiple, outputting this:

```
'"status":200,"ts":1543039907796,"userAgent":"Mozilla 5.0"'
```

Comment: In my case '""status"":200,""ts"":1543039907796,""userAgent"":"Mozilla 5.0""' it was just an example. I mean is a huge file with json format so is variable... the """ appears just in some places, that file comes from a process and actually is a log file

Comment: Ok, so you need to update your question with these details if your objective is not met. As your question in worded currently I believe I answered it

Comment: But either way if you have this string as a variable and it is a huge JSON string it should work just the same.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've updated my question. thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

Your text to be replaced starts with the double quotation marks. Python accepts them as the string symbols. Try following:

```
text="""
""status"":200,""ts"":1543039907796,""userAgent"":"Mozilla 5.0""
"""
text.replace('""','"')
```

This yields:

```
'\n"status":200,"ts":1543039907796,"userAgent":"Mozilla 5.0"\n'
```

You could get rid of `'\n'` characters in any way.